# I sit possible to display tick mark labels at an angle in a Google Visualization chart?

Tags: google-visualization

Good morning:

I want to display my bar charts tick mark labels at an angle.  Is that possible?  My code, using a simple chart from Google is included.

Thanks for your assistance,
Natalie

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

            ['Topping', 'Slices',],

            ['Mushrooms', 300],
            ['Onions', 100],
            ['Olives', 500],
            ['Zucchini', 200],
            ['Pepperoni', 100]
      ]);

        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                        'width':400,
                        'height':300,
                        'hAxis':{
                        ticks: [250, 300,],
                        gridlines: {color: 'blue'},
                        textStyle:{color: 'blue',}
                        },
                       };

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `slantedText: true` to your configuration options

if you need a specific angle, use `slantedTextAngle: number`

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Topping', 'Slices',],
        ['Mushrooms', 300],
        ['Onions', 100],
        ['Olives', 500],
        ['Zucchini', 200],
        ['Pepperoni', 100]
      ]),
      {
        title: 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        hAxis: {
          ticks: [250, 300],
          gridlines: {color: 'blue'},
          // slant hAxis labels
          slantedText: true,
          slantedTextAngle: 33,
          textStyle: {color: 'blue'}
        }
      }
    );
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect again WhiteHat.  Thanks.  I have looked and looked all over the Google documentation for this answer and was not able to find it.  Is there documentation that identifies all the "options" possibilities to which you could direct me?

Comment: unfortunately, there isn't one page that shows them all, the `slanted` options are listed in the configuration options for the [LineChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) -- it seems to list the most -- i usually check there or the [ColumnChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options)